# I want to Show the Hidden Shrunken Header and Not Shrink The Already Visible Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, header

http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll

Im using this method,... How do I edit the JQuery and CSS to give me only the small version of the header at the top of my page once I hit the scroll point from the top, then making it disappear when scrolling back to the top, instead of shrinking and growing a much bigger header like in the tutorial?

Here is the JS by the way:

```
<!-- js -->
<script src="http://dageniusmarketer.com/wordpress/wp-content/classie.js"></script>
<script>
    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 265,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");
            } else {
                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<!--Resizable Scrolling Header-->
<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            LOGO
        </h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Lorem</a>
            <a href="">Ipsum</a>
            <a href="">Dolor</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- /header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the page source for your example with updated paths (seems to be the code you are trying to reproduce...) I would start by copying and pasting it into an index.html file and modifying it from there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- title and meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<title>Header Resize On Scroll with Animations</title>

<!-- css -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://callmenick.com/_development/resize-header-on-scroll/css/style.css" />

<!-- js -->
<script src="http://callmenick.com/_development/resize-header-on-scroll/js/classie.js"></script>
<script>
    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 300,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");
            } else {
                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();
</script>
</head>



<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            LOGO
        </h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Lorem</a>
            <a href="">Ipsum</a>
            <a href="">Dolor</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header><!-- /header -->
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Header Resize On Scroll with Animations</h1>
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll">&laquo; Go back to this tutorial?</a><br>
                    <a href="http://callmenick.com/">&laquo; Go back to all tutorials?</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="color">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Cupcakes for the people!</h1>
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Chocolate, vanilla, and red velvet</h1>
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="color">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Come to me!</h1>
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Sugar rush, oh my...</h1>
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div><!-- #main -->


<footer>
<div id="info-bar">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <span class="all-tutorials"><a href="http://callmenick.com/">&larr; all tutorials</a></span>
        <span class="back-to-tutorial"><a href="http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll">back to the tutorial</a></span>
    </div>
</div><!-- /#top-bar -->
</footer><!-- /footer -->



</div><!-- /#wrapper -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-34160351-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.fusionads.net/fusion.js?zoneid=1332&serve=C6SDP2Y&placement=callmenickcom" id="_fusionads_js"></script>
<script>
var interval = setInterval(function(){

  // check for when fusionads shows up in DOM
  var fusionad = document.getElementById("fusionads");

  if (fusionad){

    // clear the interval so we stop looping
    clearInterval(interval);

    // add the close ad button
    var closead = document.createElement("a");
    closead.id = "close-fusionad";
    closead.innerHTML = "x";
    closead.href = "#";
    document.body.appendChild(closead);

    // close the ad
    document.getElementById("close-fusionad").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.remove();
      fusionad.remove();
    });

  }

},100); // check every 100ms
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

To achieve the goal of Starting with it large, letting it go small and preventing it from going large again:

- remove the `else` statement following `if (distanceY > shrinkOn)`

.

```
<script>
    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 300,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");
            } 
//          else {
//                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
//                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
//                }
//            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();
</script>
```

Comment: do you know how to edit it to achieve the effect im looking for?